# How do i get my 2 divs aligned with the middle one?

Tags: html, css

In this screenshot you can see that the 2 divs on the bottom wont go upwards, but if I remove one of them, the other one goes up. If someone is able to help me, please explain how you did it. I've been struggling for a while now.

[image]

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
 body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #36536B;
}
header {
  background: url(http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/429358847309389564/B2112B09FD47EAAD9D4DC304C26CE583794A5844/);
  width: 770px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2
}
.container {
  max-width: 770px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left,
.right,
.middle {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: initial;
}
.wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1060px;
}
.right {
  margin-right: 0px;
  float: right;
  position: initial;
}
.left-header,
.right-header,
.middle-header {
  background: #58C5B3;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: initial;
}
.middle {
  width: 498px;
  position: initial;
}
.left-text,
.right-text,
.middle-text {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: initial;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #55A7DB;
  color: black;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: .2em;
  width: 780px;
  height: 42px;
  border-right: .2em;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 010px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 10px;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #58c5b3;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.design {
  padding: 3px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.pluss {
  color: #7dc3b7;
}
.minus {
  color: #c5618b;
}
.space {
  height: 20px;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  border: 5px solid white;
}
input[type=submit] {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: .2em;
  border: 0 none;
  background-color: #f1f2f3;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.smatt {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.avatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>NEWS</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>ADMINS</a>
      </li>
      <li style="float:right">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>LOGIN</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <br>

    <!-- LEFT  -->
    <div class="left" style="width: 25%">
      <div class="left-header">
        brukerprofil<i style="float:right" class="fa fa-user fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="left-text">
        <!-- -->
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /// left-->

    <!-- MIDDLE -->
    <div class="middle" style="width: 47%">
      <div class="middle-header" style="background-color: #ce5b5b">
        Welcome to (servername)!<i style="float:right;" class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="middle-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /// middle-->

    <!-- RIGHT -->
    <div class="right" style="width: 25%;">
      <div class="right-header" style="background-color: #e3c155 ">
        logg inn<i style="float:right;" class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="right-text" style="padding 7px">
        <!-- -->
        <input type="text" name="Brukernavn" placeholder="Brukernavn">
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="Passord:" placeholder="Passord">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Logg inn">
        <span class="smatt">, eller registrer.</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <p>
      <div class="left" style="width: 25%">
        <div class="left-header" style="background-color: #ce5b5b">
          Welcome to (servername)!<i style="float:right;" class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="left-text">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- RIGHT -->
      <p>
        <div class="right" style="width: 25%;">
          <div class="right-header" style="background-color: #e3c155 ">
            logg inn<i style="float:right;" class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="right-text" style="padding 7px, margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <!-- -->
            <input type="text" name="Brukernavn" placeholder="Brukernavn">
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="Passord:" placeholder="Passord">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Logg inn">
            <span class="smatt">, eller registrer.</span>
          </div>
        </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

What I have tried:

I tried to change the margin: 0 on the divs, but just made it worse.
I also know that the height of the middle div is the one who decides where the 2 divs are, how do i make that do not happend?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/esvL055x/

Comment: You should put left panels inside the div with a class .left, and the right panels inside the div with a class .right respectively. So you basically end up having .left, .middle and .right divs with their content inside them.

Comment: @localZero, can you do it for me? didnt get it to work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/esvL055x/1/

Just clean up that a bit and you're good to go

Comment: @joe you need to create columns and then place the elements in each column, i.e. `<div class="left"><div class="left-one"></div><div class="left-two"></div></div><div class="middle"><div class="middle-one"></div><div class="middle-two"></div><div class="right"><div class="right-one"></div><div class="right-two"></div></div>`.

Comment: can you fix that in the jsfiddle sir? @hungerstar

Comment: Nope, I cannot. SO is not a code writing service. It will benefit you more to study and **understand** example code to properly implement it for your use case. If I do it for you, you learn nothing.

Comment: @hungerstar, thats the problem. I didnt undedrstand, so if you could do it for me, then explain. It would be better.

Comment: Sorry @joe, I basically did it for you in a previous comment. It's pretty basic, please put in some effort.